# Sharepoint: Advance permissions menu, by default

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the default popup/page for granting access?
We don't use the default popup at all, always skip it to use the advance permissions instead.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, there is currently no way to achieve this. This by design and we have no way to customize it. You can share your idea to Microsoft in this feedback portal https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. Microsoft will take your idea into consideration if it is highly voted.